# Why is Java not executing Commands in chronological order?

Tags: java, swing

I had this question while setting a JLabel visible when a button is clicked it is like a loading icon. The `p.make()` method is executed but the Label is still invisible after the Method returns the Label is visible.
Can someone explain what is happening?

ActionPerformed:

```
String[] args = {jTextFieldDrgzusatzVariable.getText(),jTextFieldAusgabe.getText(),"C:\\CPOracle",jTextFieldKatalog.getText()};

 this.jLblLoading.setVisible(true); 
 if(jLblLoading.isVisible()){
        try{   
       new P21Make(args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3]).make();
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: IOException in p.make()? Is it a new Thread? All Swing GUI Things have to be done in the EDT...

Comment: it has 350 lines so I it think it is to big

Comment: have you tried to call `jLblLoading.revalidate()` and `jLblLoading.repaint()` after the if?

Comment: yes i have it makes no difference

Comment: I want to post a solution but who can i add code to a comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is very simple: Swing is single threaded (see the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information).

What happens is that the `actionPerformed` method is called on the Swing thread (the **E**(vent)**D**(ispatch)**T**(hread)). When the

```
this.jLblLoading.setVisible(true);
```

statement is reached, it will immediately mark the `jLblLoading` as visible. However, this has no effect yet on the UI. The UI needs to be repainted before the change in visibility has any effect. This repaint is *scheduled* on the EDT (which is not the same as immediately executed).

This explains why your

```
if(jLblLoading.isVisible()){
```

check succeeds, and you still do not see the difference in the UI. The component is marked as visible, but the repaint is still pending. The repaint will remain pending until the EDT becomes available again. Since the thing that is currently occupying the EDT is your `actionPerformed` call, the rest of the code in that `actionPerformed` method will be executed before the repaint (meaning before you see a change in the UI).

Your solution using a different thread can indeed fix this. You can however only use that if the `new P21Make(...).make()` does not affect the UI. If that statement interacts with Swing components in any way, it should be executed on the EDT. In that case, an alternative is to wrap the statement in a `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` call.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to allow actions which modify the gui to complete.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html